# tabular format, vertical line format not included in header

Tags: tables, miktex

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\toprule
 & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{ID}} & $\mathbf{T^x_{EO}}$ & $\mathbf{T^y_{EO}}$ & $\mathbf{T^z_{EO}}$ & $\mathbf{R^x_{EO}}$ & $\mathbf{R^y_{EO}}$ & $\mathbf{R^z_{EO}}$ & \textbf{RMS} \\
 & & [m] & [m] & [m] & [deg] & [deg] & [deg] & [px] \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{P\textit{n}P-LM}} & A & 2.748 & -0.135 & 2.175 & 119.232 & 1.368 & -76.261 & 0.240 \\
& B & 2.690  & 0.768  & 2.128 & 124.905 & -1.972 & -91.559 & 0.247 \\
& C & -1.576 & 1.139  & 2.146 & 120.264 & 1.428  & 98.205  & 0.255 \\
& D & -1.575 & -0.122 & 2.165 & 119.634 & -0.818 & 85.313  & 0.231 \\\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{EP\textit{n}P}}& A & 2.722 & -0.161 & 2.345 & 121.639 & 1.828 & -75.974 & 0.463 \\
& B & 2.649  & 0.729  & 2.259 & 127.082 & -0.881 & -91.444 & 0.432 \\
& C & -1.565 & 1.148  & 2.246 & 121.639 & 1.250  & 98.377  & 0.389 \\
& D & -1.547 & -0.077 & 2.238 & 120.951 & 0.199  & 85.428  & 0.372 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I want to add a vectical line that covers [A-D] on the right side of EPnP and PnP-LM. If I do `{c|cccccccc}` it creates a vertical line also in the header which I dont want.

Comment: you seem to be using `booktabs` as well, so vertical lines will not look pretty as they won't touch the `\midrule`. however, if you need to remove them on some cells, just put `\multicolumn{1}{}{}` in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to ArTourter answer, considering his/her comment (by which I agree) with emphasis on formatting numbers in table. For this I added two packages: `siunitx` (fur numbers formatting) and `stackengine` (for setting of column heads):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{stackengine}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc*{2}{S[table-format=-1.3]}
                       S[table-format= 1.3]
                       S
                       S[table-format=-1.3]
                       S[table-format= 3.3]
                       S[table-format= 1.3]}
    \toprule
%\multicolumn{1}{c}{}% in case, if you prefer to have vertical line after first column ...
    &   {\textbf{ID}} 
        &   {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
            &   {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^y_{EO}}$}}
                &   {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
                    &   {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
                        &   {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^y_{EO}}$}}
                            &   {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
                                &   {\stackon{[px]}{\textbf{RMS}\vphantom{y}}}   \\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{P\textit{n}P-LM}}
    & A & 2.748  & -0.135 & 2.175 & 119.232 & 1.368  & -76.261 & 0.240  \\
    & B & 2.690  & 0.768  & 2.128 & 124.905 & -1.972 & -91.559 & 0.247  \\
    & C & -1.576 & 1.139  & 2.146 & 120.264 & 1.428  & 98.205  & 0.255  \\
    & D & -1.575 & -0.122 & 2.165 & 119.634 & -0.818 & 85.313  & 0.231  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{EP\textit{n}P}}
    & A & 2.722  & -0.161 & 2.345 & 121.639 & 1.828  & -75.974 & 0.463  \\
    & B & 2.649  & 0.729  & 2.259 & 127.082 & -0.881 & -91.444 & 0.432  \\
    & C & -1.565 & 1.148  & 2.246 & 121.639 & 1.250  & 98.377  & 0.389  \\
    & D & -1.547 & -0.077 & 2.238 & 120.951 & 0.199  & 85.428  & 0.372  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the `booktabs` package as you are using `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`. These command add some space above and below the line. Therefore if you also use vertical lines in your table, they will not touch the horizontal lines, which may not look as good.

That being said, you can remove a vertical line defined in the table header on a cell to cell basis using `\multicolumn`.

`\multicolumn` take 3 arguments:

1. number of column merged (in your case 1)
2. style of the cell in the same format as you have in the header and will remove any already defined.
3. the content of the column

so for your case, if you define your table as you tried with `{c|cccccccc}`, you can add `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` in the cell you do not want the vertical bar to appear:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|cccccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{ID}} & $\mathbf{T^x_{EO}}$ & $\mathbf{T^y_{EO}}$ & $\mathbf{T^z_{EO}}$ & $\mathbf{R^x_{EO}}$ & $\mathbf{R^y_{EO}}$ & $\mathbf{R^z_{EO}}$ & \textbf{RMS} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & [m] & [m] & [m] & [deg] & [deg] & [deg] & [px] \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{P\textit{n}P-LM}} & A & 2.748 & -0.135 & 2.175 & 119.232 & 1.368 & -76.261 & 0.240 \\
& B & 2.690  & 0.768  & 2.128 & 124.905 & -1.972 & -91.559 & 0.247 \\
& C & -1.576 & 1.139  & 2.146 & 120.264 & 1.428  & 98.205  & 0.255 \\
& D & -1.575 & -0.122 & 2.165 & 119.634 & -0.818 & 85.313  & 0.231 \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{EP\textit{n}P}}& A & 2.722 & -0.161 & 2.345 & 121.639 & 1.828 & -75.974 & 0.463 \\
& B & 2.649  & 0.729  & 2.259 & 127.082 & -0.881 & -91.444 & 0.432 \\
& C & -1.565 & 1.148  & 2.246 & 121.639 & 1.250  & 98.377  & 0.389 \\
& D & -1.547 & -0.077 & 2.238 & 120.951 & 0.199  & 85.428  & 0.372 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which gives you this.

[image]

I still think this is unnecessary and the original table looked better but...

Comment: You are right. But if I dont visualize it first I cant decide.